# Equivalent MDX calculation for DAX SUMX

Tags: excel, pivot-table, mdx

i need to get the equivalent of using SUMX for the Change Net Patient Revenue column and Change Payer column.  It is a complicated calculated measure for both but I just want the total to sum as seen in the corrected total row as seen in pic.  I am using excel 2016 and can modify the mdx or calculated measure.

[image]